# Powershell: Placing Second X-Axis on bar chart

Tags: powershell, mschart

The following chart using powershell and csv file.
I would also like to add the 'Time' as the top secondary X-Axis, but I do not know how to add it to the series.

I suspect it's the line with `$chart1.Series["Elapse"].Points.DataBindXY($date, $totalMinutes)
$chart1.Series["Elapse"].Points.DataBindXY($date, $totalMinutes)`, but how is DataBind XY determined with two X-Axis?

[image: Bar Chart]
CVS:

```
Date,Time,Attempts,TotalMinutes
06/08/2020,20:48,6,6.08613289666667
06/08/2020,21:20,9,9.10416342666667
06/09/2020,07:25,2,2.06852810833333
```

powershell:

```
#CONSTANTS
$directory = "C:\Users\gamble.pw\Desktop\powershell"
$csvFile = "logfile.csv"

#chart object
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization")
$chart1 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
$chart1.Width = 2000
$chart1.Height = 1000
$chart1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White

#title 
[void]$chart1.Titles.Add("Login Time")
$chart1.Titles[0].Font = "segoeuilight,20pt"
$chart1.Titles[0].Alignment = "topLeft"

#chart area
$chartarea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
$chartarea.Name = "ChartArea1"
$chartarea.AxisY.Title = "Elapse Time in Minutes"
$chartarea.AxisX.Title = "Date"
$chartarea.AxisX2.Title = "Time"
$chartarea.AxisY.Interval = 1
$chartarea.AxisX.Interval = 1 
$chart1.ChartAreas.Add($chartarea)


#data source
$datasource = Import-Csv "$directory\$csvFile"
$date = $datasource.Date 
$time = $datasource.Time 
$totalMinutes = $datasource.TotalMinutes

Write-Host $date
Write-Host $time
Write-Host $attempts
Write-Host $totalMinutes


#data series
[void]$chart1.Series.Add("Elapse")
#$chart1.Series["Elapse"].ChartType = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType]::Line
$chart1.Series["Elapse"].BorderWidth = 2
$chart1.Series["Elapse"].Points.DataBindXY($date, $totalMinutes)


$chart1.SaveImage("$directory\Bar_Chart_Login.png","png")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a different series for each axis.  You have to define in the Series which axes to use.  Once you know which axis you want the Series to go with, you can set it's `AxistType`.

```
$chart1.Series["Elapse"].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
$chart1.Series["Elapse"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```

Once you have your AxisType set, when you databind the Series it will know which axis to display it on.